# Menu tabs don't remain opened on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this side menu, where I added some session storage to keep my active tabs opened even if I reload the page. 
I am really not comfortable with js and I am stuck now. How can I fix this code to keep the active tab opened on reload?

here is my my_menu in raw html, my javascript_menu and the CSS:

I have no error in the browser console

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {


  var sessionItem = sessionStorage.getItem('activedropdown') || null;
  var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-dropdown');
  var i;


  if (sessionItem !== null) {
    var dropdownParent = document.getElementById(sessionItem);
    openDropdown(dropdownParent);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      openDropdown(this);
      if (document.getElementsByClassName('active').length > 0) {
        activeTab = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].id;
        sessionStorage.setItem('activedropdown', activeTab);
      } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem('activedropdown', null);
      }
    });
  };


  function openDropdown(dropdownParent) {

    $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);

      if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {

        $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
        //$(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        $(this).removeClass("active");

      } else {

        $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
        $(this).next(".sidebar-submenu").slideDown(200);
        //$(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
      }
    });
  };


  $("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").addClass('reduced-menu')
    $("#show-sidebar").show();
    $("#close-sidebar").hide()
  });

  $("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
    $(".page-wrapper").removeClass('reduced-menu');
    $("#show-sidebar").hide();
    $("#close-sidebar").show()
  });


});
```

```css
@keyframes swing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes sonar {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.page-wrapper .sidebar-wrapper,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-dropdown>a:after,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:before,
.sidebar-wrapper ul li a i,
.page-wrapper .page-content,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a,
#show-sidebar,
#close-sidebar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


/*----------------page-wrapper----------------*/

// .page-wrapper {
//   height: 100vh;
// }
.page-wrapper .theme {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.page-wrapper .theme.chiller-theme {
  background: #1e2229;
}


/*----------------toggeled sidebar----------------*/

.page-wrapper.toggled .sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .page-wrapper.toggled .page-content {
    padding-left: 300px;
  }
}


/*----------------show sidebar button----------------*/

#show-sidebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}

#close-sidebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.page-wrapper.toggled #show-sidebar {
  left: -40px;
}


/*----------------sidebar-wrapper----------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 242px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.sidebar-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*----------------sidebar-content----------------*/

.sidebar-content {
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-content.desktop {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


/*--------------------sidebar-brand----------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand {
  //margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand #close-sidebar #show-sidebar {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/*--------------------sidebar-header----------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*----------------------sidebar-menu-------------------------*/

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .header-menu span {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 20px 5px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 30px 8px 20px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a:hover>i::before {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: swing ease-in-out 0.5s 1 alternate;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown>a:after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f105";
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  background: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 14px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu ul {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:before {
  content: "\f111";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 8px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a span.label,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a span.badge {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a .badge,
.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a .label {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-submenu {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active>a:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 17px;
}


/*--------------------------page-content-----------------------------*/

.page-wrapper .page-content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.page-wrapper .page-content>div {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.page-wrapper .page-content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*------scroll bar---------------------*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  height: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #525965;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #525965;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #525965;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}


/*-----------------------------chiller-theme-------------------------------------------------*/

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper {
  background: #111;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu {
  // border-top: 1px solid #3a3f48;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-role,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info .user-status,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a {
  color: #818896;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li:hover>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active>a,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-header .user-info,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-brand>a:hover,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:hover i {
  color: #b8bfce;
}

.page-wrapper.chiller-theme.toggled #close-sidebar #show-sidebar {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.page-wrapper.chiller-theme.toggled #close-sidebar:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.page-wrapper.chiller-theme.toggled #show-sidebar:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper ul li:hover a i,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li a:hover:before,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu:focus+span,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown.active a i {
  color: #16c7ff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(22, 199, 255, 0.5);
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu ul li a i,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown div,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search input.search-menu,
.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-search .input-group-text {
  background: #222;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .header-menu span {
  color: #6c7b88;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer {
  background: #3a3f48;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 5px #282c33;
  border-top: 1px solid #464a52;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.chiller-theme .sidebar-footer>a:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.reduced-menu {
  .sidebar-submenu {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .badge {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-title {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; //left: -300px;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown>a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-menu .sidebar-dropdown .sidebar-submenu li {
    padding-left: 2px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-wrapper chiller-theme toggled reduced-men">
  <nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-container">
      <div class="sidebar-brand">
        <div id="close-sidebar">
          Left<i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="show-sidebar">
          Right<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="article">
              <i class="fas fa-tshirt"></i>
              <span class="menu-title">Articles</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a class="drop-item" href="/admin/list">All articles</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="drop-item" href="/admin/products/new">Add article</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="suppliers">
              <i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>
              <span class="menu-title">Suppliers</span>
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a class="drop-item" href="/admin/suppliers/new">Add Supplier</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="drop-item" href="/admin/suppliers">All Suppliers</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar-menu  -->
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Although not the issue, you have an extra closing `</li>` tag.  I may know what the issue is.  Could you also include your CSS so I can test it?

Comment: Hello I added the css